# How much UI skills are needed for a springmvc developer

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Im an android developer now i want to switch my career to java web developer, I have learned Jsf and Spring mvc, my question is how much UI skills are required to work in spring mvc

Comment: Please read on what Stack Overflow is really for - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn SpringMVC I would recommend learning the basics in these.

1. Servlets
2. JSP
3. Tomcat (or another web application container)

For specifically UI part you should know basic of HTML, JSP, CSS and JavaScript.
Now its depends on you that what type is expertise you want to achieve and to which level.

Comment: I do not have job yet I want to know how much css knowledge   should I have   before going to job?

Comment: As a developer if you know the basics to check the impact on the page of the css like change of background color, font size, font type, border size type and table styles etc then that will ok. But incase you want to be a designed you need indepth knowledge of CSS and good hands on practices.